# Numpy divide doesn't return floats

Tags: list, numpy, divide

When I run:

```
np.divide(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([2, 2, 4, 4, 4]))
```

OR

```
np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])/np.array([2, 2, 4, 4, 4])
```

OR

```
np.true_divide(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([2, 2, 4, 4, 4]))
```

The output I get:

```
array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1.])
```

Even when the numbers are specified as floats like `[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]`, the result is the same.

**Expected output**:

```
array([0., 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0])
```

I am unable to understand why the result is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

The print precision was set to `precision=0`.

*Took me a while to figure that out!*

Got fixed when I did:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
```